# meta charset = UTF-8 vs charset = iso-8859-1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why are we specifying *charset = "UTF-8"* in the *meta* tag?

Is it mandatory to specify this in our web pages?

Does it have any other value other than *utf-8*?

And what is this *iso-8859-1*? Where and when should we use them?

Comment: Yes, there are many [other values](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) that can be used but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) says use UTF-8.

Comment: Please help me out when and where to use UTF ans ISO?

Comment: Note: If present, the meta charset value should match the character encoding that the document was written/saved with. A library that saves or streams HTML documents should make sure that it does. So, the question splits: 1) Is the tag necessary? 2) Which character encoding should be used?

Comment: There must be duplicate somewhere from 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UTF-8**

UTF-8 (UCS Transformation Format 8) is the World Wide Web's most common character encoding. UTF-8 is backward-compatible with ASCII and can represent any standard Unicode character. The first 128 UTF-8 characters precisely match the first 128 ASCII characters (numbered 0-127), meaning that existing ASCII text is already valid UTF-8. After the first 128 code points, it utilizes a multibyte approach for additional characters.

**ISO-8859-1**

By contrast, ISO-8859-1 is a single-byte encoding scheme. The major downfall of this type of encoding is its inability to accommodate languages that are composed of more than 128 symbols.

Source: [MDN entry on UTF-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/UTF-8)

Comment: Please help me out when and where to use UTF ans ISO?

Comment: UTF is much more versatile than ISO encoding, especially with respect to modern clients. HTML5 default encoding is UTF-8. Some *really* old/broken clients don't handle UTF well, but I can't imagine those are an issue to just about everyone.

Comment: 1) ISO-8859-1 has 256 characters. 2) The HTML document encoding does not restrict the text content because: a) All text content in HTML is Unicode b) a Unicode character that is not in the document encoding character set can be represented using numeric character entity references (e.g., &#x1f6b2; for ).

Answer (score 2):

To display an HTML page correctly, a web browser must know the character set used in the page.

See more at *[HTML Encoding (Character Sets)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)* (W3Schools).

Comment: Please help me out when and where to use UTF ans ISO?

Comment: UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding that can represent any Unicode character. ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding that can represent the first 256 Unicode characters. Both encode ASCII exactly the same way. If you want world domination, use UTF-8 all the way, because this covers every human character available at the world, including Asian, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic, Greek and so on, while ISO-8859 is only restricted to Latin characters.

Comment: If the HTML document is sent via HTTP, the HTTP header Content-Type would fulfill the same requirement.